# displaying google map in Jquery tabbed pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter-2

Can anybody help me to display google map in jquery tabbed pane!
I am using codigniter, where i get the latitude and logitude from controller file.

My concern is that map is not properly displayed in the tab pane.

Thanks

Comment: Please use a service such as jsfiddle to show what code you have right now. Otherwise, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: please refer this link:http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers     but i have tabbed pane in view page  where i need to place the code  <?php  echo $map['js'];  echo $map['html']; ?>;

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of static maps api? you can create images out of google maps using it.

Read more about it here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/

I tried to implement it inside the tabs and it worked fine. Check out this example here http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Lyu/

Seomthing like below will create the map

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```